# i am fetching data from api jsonp. all the data are available to use but the logoUrl does not work

Tags: javascript, jsonp

this is what the URL looks like in the object.

logoURL: "/rimg/provider-logos/airlines/v/FJ.png?crop=false&width=108&height=92&fallback=default1.png&_v=9b38c3bf0c4447c0b6d5b340dc9c41b7"

it seems like there should be something before the first slash.

and here is the whole object.
{
alliance: "OW"
code: "FJ"
defaultName: null
logoURL: "/rimg/provider-logos/airlines/v/FJ.png?crop=false&width=108&height=92&fallback=default1.png&_v=9b38c3bf0c4447c0b6d5b340dc9c41b7"
name: "Fiji Airways"
phone: "+679 672 0888"
site: "https://www.fijiairways.com"
usName: null
__clazz: "com.r9.harmony.httpd.mobileapis.AirlineMobile"
}

thanks in advance

Comment: You have to share more details than this like your code and output so we can help you solve your problem

Comment: I imagine you'll need to add the host name (whatever that is) to that URL if you want to download the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the url is missing a server name. try putting "https://www.company.com" before the url, where company is the name of the host.